# Number expected error on sort

Tags: javascript, sorting

Other browsers work fine but in IE i get Number Expected when using the following code and it runs into a null object on the sort function.
http://jsfiddle.net/R3ndd/2/

```
function list_response(jsonData) {
"use strict";
var lists = document.getElementById("lists"), anchors =     document.getElementById("anchors"), jItems = jsonData.items;
var results = [], anks = [], vList, pListName, item, videoItem;

var i, j, jLen, iLen = jItems.length;
for (var i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
    if(jItems[i] != null ){
    jItems[i].nameLower = jItems[i].name.toLowerCase();
    }
}

jItems.sort(function (a, b) {
    if(a != null && b != null){
    return a.nameLower.localeCompare(b.nameLower);
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**My Solution**

I decided to remove the null object (which works) from json using the following:

```
var y;
for (var x in jItems) {
    if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(jItems,x)) {
        y = jItems[x];
        if (y==="null" || y===null || y==="" || typeof y === "undefined") {
            delete jItems[x];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that all of your entries have well-defined name attributes going in?

Comment: Can you post the iLen and jItems vars? And preferably the rest of the code related to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why IE does that, but it is it's habit to trouble us good people :). Well, I think this will be better way.

```
/* NOT NEEDED.
for (var i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
    if(jItems[i] != null ){
    jItems[i].nameLower = jItems[i].name.toLowerCase();
    }
}*/

jItems.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a && b ? a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase()) : 0;
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Well, I think I know where IE is troubling. Sorry MS, this time IE hasn't any fault. What happened was that in case where either `a` or `b` were `null`/`''`/`false` (or any *falsy* value), your callback didn't return any value. That explians the 'Number expected' error. But I took care of that, so my answer will probably work. :)

Comment: Good catch, I was trying to get `localeCompare` to throw the error but couldn't.

Comment: @Parth tried your code and get Object doesn't support this property or method on the return. more specifically: a.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: can u fiddle it out please? That would help in error detection.